# My first means the same as my last, and both mean the same as my whole

Tags: riddle

> My first means the same as my last, 
> and both mean the same as my whole.
>  When you come out of me, 
> you're not the same on the outside anymore.
>  I'm part of an immersive experience.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 12):

You are

> a bath tub.

First, last, and whole mean the same:

> "I'm going to get into the bath."
> "I'm going to get into the tub."
> "I'm going to get into the bath tub."

When you get out ...

> ... of the bath tub, you're clean on the outside.
>
> A bath tub is an immersive experience.